# How to put multiple lines of code into a format.html block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My controller is

```
def destroy
@image.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: 'success' }
end
```

end

I want that request from html then it redirect to :back like

```
flash[:notice] = "Image Successfully deleted"
redirect_to :back
```

it works fine when I can't deal with json. I want to combine both of them so they send response accordingly to html or ajax request

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just put it inside the respond_to block for the html format

```
def destroy
  @image.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html do
      flash[:notice] = "Image Successfully deleted"
      redirect_to :back
    end
    format.json do
      render json: 'success'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put multiple lines into a block.

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    flash[:notice] = "Image Successfully deleted"
    redirect_to :back
  end
  format.json { render json: 'success' }
end
```